# Why does `DEBUG=foo node index.js` fails in `scripts` section of `package.json`

Tags: node.js, bash, package.json

I'm on Windows 10, but I'm using `git bash`. When running from `git bash` the following:

```
DEBUG=foo node index.js
```

it works fine and sets the environment variable `DEBUG`. But if I put it into the `scripts` section of the `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "DEBUG=foo node index.js"
  },
```

and run the following from `git bash` I get the following error:

```
$ npm start

> nodejs@1.0.0 start C:\Users\maksym.koretskyi\Desktop\nodejs
> DEBUG=foo node index.js

'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why the behaviour?

Comment: Your error comes as a result of an instruction  executed under a `Windows` environment (note the `batch` keyword) and not the `bash` shell.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought. Do you know why the `DEBUG=foo node index.js` is executed under Windows env even if I run `npm start` from `git bash`?

Comment: Can you try re-affirming once again, if `node` is installed peroperly, may be checking `$PATH` in `Git bash` to see if it has the path where node is installed

Comment: it should have, since `DEBUG=foo node index.js` is executed fine from `git bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're running it on Windows.

Assuming that you have Bash working as you said, I would make a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEBUG=foo node index.js
```

called e.g. `run-debug` and use:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "bash run-debug"
},
```

in `package.json` to make sure that the `DEBUG=foo node index.js` command is interpreted by Bash and not command.com or whatever the shell in Windows is called. See [Issue #6543: npm scripts shell select](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6543).

For cases when you want it to run even on systems without Bash, for maximum cross-platform compatibility, it's even better to use a Node script instead of a shell script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node run-debug.js"
},
```

In this case the `run-debug.js` could contain something like:

```
let env = Object.create(process.env);
env.DEBUG = 'foo';
spawn('node', ['app.js'], {env});
```

See also:

- [NPM script under cygwin/windows: the syntax of the command is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107780/npm-script-under-cygwin-windows-the-syntax-of-the-command-is-incorrect/42108180#42108180)

Comment: thanks, that might be a solution, but I want to understand why `npm` runs commands under Windows, and not `git bash`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed, I've found the following [thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6543) and it states that:

> The shell config variable is only used by the npm explore command,
>   which forks a subshell. It's not meant to be used to allow you to use,
>   say, bash on Windows, or switch between Powershell and cmd.exe.
>   **Scripts are always run by the shebang line on Unix, and cmd.exe on
>   Windows**.

So it seems that's by design and there's no way to change it.