# Forever Commandline with NPM arguments

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, command-line-arguments, forever

I'm building a project which I have multiple instances of running, with the exact same code, using forever.
With forever, it's possible to set an id, using `--id "id"`.

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "forever": "forever start --id $1 -c \"npm start\" ./"
  },
  "author": "Renzo <renzo@geex.company>",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This way, I'm trying to make a standard for different app instances like:

`npm run forever cms`

The idea is that this would start the app with `id` `cms`.
But instead, it lists the app with id `true`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
npm run forever cms
```

to this:

```
npm run forever -- cms
```

but you'd also have to change the order of arguments in package.json.

Also, you can put this in a script, like forever.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
forever start --id $1 -c "npm start" ./
```

and this in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "forever": "sh forever.sh"
},
```

and then use this from the command line:

```
npm run forever -- cms
```

To make it work on Windows see these answers:

- [Why does `DEBUG=foo node index.js` fails in `scripts` section of `package.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379090/why-does-debug-foo-node-index-js-fails-in-scripts-section-of-package-json/41379524#41379524)
- ['bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438587/bash-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/42439350#42439350)
- [NPM script under cygwin/windows: the syntax of the command is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107780/npm-script-under-cygwin-windows-the-syntax-of-the-command-is-incorrect/42108180#42108180)

Comment: This idea did not work out in the end, and I didn't like the idea of having to make env. specific scripts, so I've solved it in a different way for now, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than an answer, but for now I'm doing it like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "forever": "forever start --id $ncmsfid -c \"npm start\" ./",
},
```

And starting it with `ncmsfid=cms npm run forever`